# How to fire a right arrow key press in firefox using selenium2library

Tags: firefox, selenium, robotframework

I am doing a robot test for some keypress event handler. Looks like firefox has some different key code , say for enter the key code in firefox is 10 instead of 13;

```
    Press Key  element  \\10
```

this would work, instead of 
`Press Key  element  \\13`

Right now, I am having a trouble finding a key code for right arrow press. 
I tried

```
    Press Key  element  \\39
```

but doesn't work, the firefox would open a search box rather than trigger a right arrow press when running this key word.

Besides, the left, up, down arrow key press (37, 38, 40) are all working correctly. 
Does any one know how to make a right arrow key press in selenium when testing in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a workaround would be run "Execute Javascript" keyword in robot to dispatch a javascript event on the page.

```
Execute Javascript  var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");evt.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0,39, 0);document.getElementsByClassName('focus')[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```